# crontab cannot read dir '../' in php script

Tags: php, cron, centos7

Why can't crontab read the '../' dir in the script, but if I access the script through a browser it can and there are no problems.

example: file.php

```
<?php

include('../config.php');
?>
```

If I run the script through the terminal config.php it can't be read '/usr/bin/php /home/example.com/public_html/cron/file.php',
whereas if I open it through a browser it runs smoothly
https://example.com/cron/file.php

I use php7.4 and os centos7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`..` references the parent directory of wherever the script is executing. It's presumably different in the two scenarios. Try `cd /home/example.com/public_html/cron && /usr/bin/php file.php` in your `crontab`, so that you're executing that in the same directory as your web page is.

Comment: It's the same, sir
resul: 
PHP Warning:  include(): Failed opening '../config.php'

Comment: Check the output of `getcwd()` in the working and non-working scenarios.

Comment: the output home/mydomain.com/public_html/cron

Comment: Edited my answer to reflect that instead, but @Sherif's answer is probably even better in this case.

Answer (score 1):

This is a perfect use case for why you should avoid using relative paths and instead stick to using **absolute** paths when including other scripts/files. PHP resolves relative paths according to the CWD (*Current Working Directory*) which will be different between your web server and your terminal. For the web server it depends on which script invoked the interpreter (in your case this is `/home/example.com/public_html/cron/file.php`). In the terminal it depends on from which directory the interpreter is loaded in the shell. In the case of a crontab it is the `$PWD` variable set in the home directory of the user that owns the crontab (so most likely `/home/{username}`). Of course that those two resolve to completely different paths.

So *instead* of all this guess work and instead of trying to change the CWD adhoc (which involves further guess work), you could simply use an absolute path at all times.

```php
<?php
include __DIR__ . '/../config.php';
```

What this allows you to do is set the absolute path to the magic `__DIR__` constant, which is a compile-time constant set to the path of the script in which it is used (in your case this is `/home/example.com/public_html/cron`). Then you can relatively go down one directory from that absolute path in order to get to `/home/example.com/public_html` from which you can now safely access `config.php` ***regardless*** of how you invoke the script and the given CWD.

Comment: this works sir thank you, is there no other way that php can read ../ on cron, like cpanel on hosting

Comment: I'm not sure how cpanel and php are even tangentially correlated in this context. When you ask PHP to `include` a file it has a very specific and well-defined manner in which it resolves the path to that file. [Those details are documented very clearly here in the PHP documentation](https://www.php.net/include).